# Stop button from losing active state in jQuery UI buttonset

Tags: mouseleave, lost-focus, jquery-ui-button, jqueryi-ui-buttonset

I'm trying to prevent my buttons from losing the active class on mouseleave, but I can't get it working.

So, my buttons are initialized with jQuery's `buttonset()`. They are **buttons**, not checkboxes. Checkboxes are out of the question because they require IDs to work.

This is my code:

```
$('.jquery_ui_buttonset', this.scope).buttonset();

$('.jquery_ui_buttonset > button', this.scope).each(function() {
    $(this).bind('mouseleave keyup mouseup blur', function(e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('ui-state-persist')) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            if (e.type == 'blur') {
                $(this).removeClass('ui-state-focus');
            }
            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
        }
    });
});
```

The idea is that if the button has the `ui-state-persist` class, it should not lose the `ui-state-active` class until both are explicitly removed. Switching of active buttons is done on click by this handler:

```
CMSPage.prototype.switchEditTab = function(e) {
    if (e.data.params.id == null) {
        return;
    }

    $('.editor .body', this.scope).hide();
    $('.editor .header button', this.scope).removeClass('ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-persist');
    $('.editor .body[data-tab-id=' + e.data.params.id + ']', this.scope).show();
    $('.editor .header button[data-id=' + e.data.params.id + ']', this.scope)
        .addClass('ui-state-active').addClass('ui-state-persist');
}
```

I've also tried adding `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` and all their combinations, but it doesn't work. And this exact same code works for regular UI buttons (ones not in buttonset).

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I still haven't resolved this problem. I would love to give you guys bounty for helping me out, but I can't since I'm a new member. Has noone ever encountered this problem in which he wanted to use `buttonset()` with persistently active buttons, and not checkboxes?